# Is there a way to recover a accidentally undo .cshtml file in github support TFS

Tags: c#, github, tfs, file-recovery

Accidentally I have undo my work (cshtml file) from my project. Is there a way to recover it from somewhere on my pc. I know about .NET reflector but its for dlls only. If there is any possible way to do it please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Are you using TFS as source control?

Comment: Source control as Github .. supports TFS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be checking in frequently or setup some sort of backup system to avoid mistakes like this. If the files are gone from your file system, they're gone.

If you are using TFS as source control.  You could also try to find the changes in the TFS temporary files in "**AppData\Local\Temp\TFSTemp**", but past that, there's no way to get them back.

Comment: Okay. That means there is no way to recover it except temp folder.

Comment: Yes, maybe a file recovery utility. But the solution is too complicated. And both the  .Net Reflector or Dotpeek  is not suitable for your situation.